# django how to use get_absolute_url with a uuid field

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have a model that has a `UUIDField` and when I use the following `

```
<h3>
<a href="{{  box.get_absolute_url }}">{{ box.title }}</a>
</h3>`
```

I get this error
`Reverse for 'detail_box' with arguments '(UUID('29eec708-4ee6-4999-838d-712441876ac7'),)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`

models.py

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Box(TimeStampModel):
    """
    Box model
    """
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    title = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    identify = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    activate = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    slug = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    activation_key = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('suggies:detail_box',
                       args=[self.slug] 
                )
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^detail/(?P<slug>[0-9A-Za-z-]+)/$', views.detail_box, name='detail_box'),
    ...
]
```

my views.py

```
def detail_box(request, slug):
    boxes = get_object_or_404(Box, slug=slug)
    return render( request, 'suggies/detail.html', {'boxes':boxes} )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `get_absolute_url` method, convert the `UUID` instance to `str`. Something like this should work.

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('suggies:detail_box', args=[str(self.slug)])
```

Comment: Thanks #v1k45! also In the model is it preferable to stringify the uuid. i.e `str(uuid.uuid4)` to avoid the error that I got in the Template.

Comment: No, there is no need to. Django will do that for you internally. `{{ obj.slug }}` will render your uuid in your template.

Comment: Thanks for the info!